# Not sure why image is no being displayed

Tags: java, image, import

So im importing an image to use as a background and for some reason its giving me:

```
 Uncaught error fetching image:
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could someone help me?

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class PixelLegendsMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   }
   public static void main(String[ ] args)throws Exception{
     PixelLegendsMain plMain = new PixelLegendsMain();
     arenaBuild arena = new arenaBuild();
     plMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


     plMain.add(arena);
     plMain.setSize(600,460);;
     plMain.setVisible(true);
     plMain.setResizable(false);
     plMain.setLocation(200, 200);
   }
 }
```

This is the main class and this:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.swing.Timer;

 public class arenaBuild extends JPanel{
   String picPath = "pictures/";
   String[] fileName = {picPath+"stageBridge.png", picPath+"turret.png"};
   ClassLoader cl = arenaBuild.class.getClassLoader();
   URL imgURL[] = new URL[2]; 
   Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
   Image imgBG;
   public arenaBuild()throws Exception{
     for (int x=0;x<2;x++){
       imgURL[x]= cl.getResource(picPath+fileName[x]);
     }
     imgBG = tk.createImage(imgURL[0]);
   }
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     g.drawImage(imgBG,0,0,600,460,0,0,600,460, this);
   }
 }
```

Thjis is where im calling the image in. Im new to this so i'd appreciate if someone can explain why this is happening and help me fix it :D

Comment: Try using "/pictures/" instead of "pictures/". And call super.paintComponent(g) - it won't fix your immediate issue, but will fix other issues your bound to have with out it

Comment: have a look this example. http://ideone.com/DpZz12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that i unfortuantely did not look at my own code long enough, it seems that i was calling the picPath twice so instead of the path being

```
 "pictures/stageBridge.png"
```

it was

```
 "pictures/pictures/stageBridge.png"
```

Sorry for the waste of time, and thank you all for answering

Comment: @caccho, i will but i have to wait 2 days, thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that your `tk.createImage(imgURL[0])` call is passing a `null` URL.

How could this happen?  Well the `ClassLoader.getResource(String)` method is [specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) as returning `null` if it can't find a resource ... so it would seem that the problem is that you are using the wrong path for the first resource.

The path you are using appears to be this: `"pictures/pictures/stageBridge.png"`:

- It seems unlikely that you really put your images in a directory called `"pictures/pictures"`.
- Since you are calling the method on a `ClassLoader` object (rather than a `Class` object), the notionally relative path you are using will be treated as an absolute path; i.e. you will get "/pictures/..." rather than "/PixelLegendsMain/pictures/..."

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the current working directory, in order to check if your images path are correct.

This is a simple way of doing that:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

Maybe the problem is that the images `pictures/tageBridge.png` and `pictures/turret.png` are not the correct path to the file.

Hope it helps!